# SQL join through denormalized table - what's the select syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having some trouble remembering my database queries - it's been a while :(

Let's say I have some tables:

```
WORDS {ID, WORD}
FILES {ID, URL}
FILES_WORDS {WORDID, FILEID, COUNT}
```

WORDS and FILES both have PK's named ID and a string for their word/path respectively.  FILES_WORDS denormaizes the many-to-many relationship and holds the count of times each word appeared in each file.

I know I can select the information for a given file like this:

```
SELECT FILES.URL, WORDS.WORD, FILES_WORDS.COUNT FROM WORDS, FILES, FILES_WORDS
    WHERE FILES_WORDS.FILEID = FILES.ID AND FILES_WORDS.WORDID = WORDS.ID AND
    IFILE.ID = 1;
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner syntax using joins and things like that though and I'm having trouble googling it or remembering it.  Can anyone help speed/clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT F.URL, W.WORD, FW.COUNT 
FROM WORDS W
  INNER JOIN FILES_WORDS FW
    ON FW.WORDID = W.ID
  INNER JOIN FILES F
    ON FW.FILEID = F.ID
WHERE FW.FILEID = 1;
```

But it is not necessarily faster. Depends on volume, indices, etc.

I used aliases (the one letter nickname for the table) because it makes it easier to follow, and I don't think you need both joins, but that also depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FILES.URL, WORDS.WORD, FILES_WORDS.COUNT 
FROM WORDS INNER JOIN FILES_WORDS ON WORDS.ID = FILES_WORDS.WORDID
          LEFT JOIN FILES ON FILES_WORDS.FILEID = FILES.ID
```

Tag on whatever you want to query for

```
IFILE.ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT f.URL, w.WORD, fw.COUNT
FROM words w INNER JOIN files_words fw 
  ON f.id = fw.fileid
INNER JOIN words w
  ON fw.wordid = w.id
WHERE f.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query-

```
SELECT FILES.URL, WORDS.WORD, FILES_WORDS.COUNT 
FROM WORDS W
Join FILES_WORDS WF
  on W.ID = WF.WORDID
Join FILES F
  on F.ID = FW.FILEID 
Where F.ID = 1;
```